# How to add pagination for JSON data in collectionview in Swift

Tags: json, swift, pagination

I have JSon model like this

```
public class SearchDataModel {
public var jsonrpc : String?
public var result : SearchResult?
}

public class SearchResult {

public var products : Array<Products>?
public var all_categories : Array<All_categories>?
}

public class Products {
public var id : Int?
public var slug : String?
public var user_id : Int?
public var price : String?
}
```

i am trying to add pagination to collectionview.. but i am getting error for that

and i am adding data to collectionview like below

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

return self.searchResultData?.result?.products?.count 
}

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VerticalSliderCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! VerticalSliderCollectionCell

    let indexData = self.searchResultData?.result?.products?[indexPath.item]
    
    cell.lbRealPrice.text = indexData?.discount_price
        // so on....
    
    return cell
 }
```

and if i am trying to add pagination to collectionview like below

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == self.searchResultData?.result?.products?.count ?? 0 - 1 {
        moreData()
    }
}

func moreData(){
    for _ in 0...10{
        self.searchResultData?.result?.products?.append(self.searchResultData?.result?.products?.last! + 1)
    }
    productCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

in this line `self.searchResultData?.result?.products?.append(self.searchResultData?.result?.products?.last! + 1)` grtting error

**error:**

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  
    if (self.searchResultData?.result?.products?.count)! > 0 {
        if indexPath.row == (self.searchResultData?.result?.products?.count)! - 1 {
            moreData()
        }
    }
}

func moreData(){
    for i in 0...10{
        self.searchResultData?.result?.products?.append((self.searchResultData?.result?.products![i])!)
    }
    productCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: `self.searchResultData?.result?.products?.last! + 1`: What does it mean to you? Not that's not even the line you "gave" in the "error". Ask you this: What's supposed to be `self.searchResultData?.result?.products?.last`? What's its type? So you'll return either that value or integer `1`? Does it make sense to you? Then, even if this work, you'll append to `self.searchResultData?.result?.products?` that?

Comment: @Larme.. first time i am working with pagination.. so i am following one tutorial and added like that.. but now i have edited my post.. in the edited code `moreData` is not calling with breakpoint and its not loading 10 items.. may i know why?

Comment: Tutorial? What tutorial? It might be interesting to share it, so we'd have more context.

Answer (score 0):

you should make some change in for loop like.

```
for i in 0...10{   
    self.searchResultData?.result?.products?.append(self.searchResultData?.result?.products[i])
}
```

in will display method

```
if self.searchResultData?.result?.products?.count! > 0 {
if indexPath.row == self.searchResultData?.result?.products?.count! - 1 {
        moreData()
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried like this.. here if i put break point then `willDisplay ` is not calling and its not working too.. where is the mistake

Comment: @learn_swift please let me know above you filled  `self.searchResultData?.result?.products?` this array

Comment: i have edited my post with your answer.. in the last pls have a look

Comment: in this line `if (self.searchResultData?.result?.products?.count)! > 0 {` brakepoint will called or not?

Comment: called the below line also called but `moreData ` not calling

Comment: any suggestion pls

Comment: @learn_swift you might have some wrong things i think here  `self.searchResultData?.result?.products?.count! - 1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232510/discussion-between-rbs-and-learn-swift).